# How to get replies on a specific tweet using Twitter Kit for Android

Tags: android, twitter, twitterkit

I am using Twitter Kit for Android in my App. I want to get all replies on a specific tweet. But the problem is Twitter does not provide any endpoints for replies/conversation as I have searched on the internet.

Everywhere, I only get [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24791980/is-there-any-work-around-on-fetching-twitter-conversations-using-latest-twitter)(using search API) kind of solution.

As It's a very old question, I wonder if someone has a better and easy solution now.

I have one more doubt, does the linked solution give all the replies?

Comment: It return all replies for a tweet but they are paginated, you have to play with  since_id and count to get all.

Comment: So, is it the only solution(using Search API)?

Comment: I didn't post it as an answer but as a comment cause I don't know about that part of your question, for what I can see that's the only option but someone else could give you more information.